# How do I skip the security question in Salesforce?

Tags: security, user-management

[image]

[image]

I had a user whose email address has been changed to another user. Now the new user gets an email to change the password along with the security question of the previous user.

How can I prevent the new user to see the security question of the previous user?

Comment: Not sure  this will help or not but check once https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005251&language=en_US

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are a system administrator you can set user password using [System.setPassword](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_setPassword) method

```
System.setPassword(userId, password as plain text)
```

1. Login as system administrator.
2. Click on Developer console as shown below

[image]

3. Select developer console and execute above code.

[image]

When the user logs in with this password, they are not prompted to create a new password and after that he can reset security question.

Comment: Thanks @Himanshu but I am not in development. Is it possible to do it without coding

Comment: Are you system administrator?

Comment: @kunalgupta https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4QBQEA3

Comment: @kunalgupta check the updated answer. it is easy enough :)

Comment: @Himanshu: I tried with your above code but got an error message .Would I have to write any class also related to this

Comment: I have attached the screenshot above

Comment: @kunalgupta  put user id in single quotes. so it will be System.setPassword('34343434fkdfhf','Alka124');

Answer (score 7):

To prevent the security question from appearing, you have to reset the password.

It looks like you let a (new) user take the account of another user. That's not a good practice. It's better to disable a user, and create a new account for the new user.

Comment: actually we had less licenses, so inorder to use the inactive one, I had to put the new user

Comment: Is there any other option?

Comment: When you deactivate a user, the licence comes available for the new user

Comment: @kunalgupta Don't recycle users if you can help it. It really does make things hard to manage after a while.